# Ng-file-upload: Sending array to Web Api

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, ng-file-upload

Using angularjs 1.3 and C# .net core web api

I have a ng-file-upload which being used to upload file. When the upload method is called I want to pass in an extra array of some data to the upload method which is then received by the method at my web api. Here is my ng-file-upload

```
factory.upload = function (file, myArray) {
    var url = '{0}upload'.format(apiPath)
    return Upload.upload({
        url: url,
        arrayKey: '',
        data: { file: file, myArray: myArray}
    }).then(function (res) {

        return res;
    });
};
```

Below is my webapi:

```
  [HttpPost("upload")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(IFormFile file, List<string> myArray)
   {
        //code
   }
```

And finally here is the array which I am trying to pass along with upload to my webapi:

```
  [
   {
     id: "1",
     name: "steve"
   },
   {
     id: "2",
     name: "adam"
   }
  ]
```

The issue is in my webapi, the myArray parameter which is to accept the array from the UI is always null. I searched online and its mentioned to add

```
 arrayKey: ''
```

But still doesnt works. Any inputs?

---Updated---

I created a string array as :

```
var cars = ["steve", "adam", "ronnie"];
```

And updated my api as:

```
List<ArrayItem> myArray
```

The above code works. So looks like there is issue with array being passed.
I am passing the following array by creating like this:

```
  var myArray= [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myJson.length; i++) {
   myArray.push({
    id: myJson[i].id,
    name: myJson[i].name,
  });                                        
 }
```

The result of above as seen in console:

```
Array(2)
0:{id: "1", name: "steve"}
1:{id: "2", name: "adam"}
```

Whats missing here?

Comment: I don't have a precise answer for you, but I do want to point out that your API method expects `List<string>`, but you're actually sending it `List<object>` (maybe not "object", you might need to create an Interface for this id/name object).
Maybe that's why it's null?

Comment: @HankScorpio I have tried with the object also still does not work. What about my ng-file-upload, any changes there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing object array, you need to define the list object to accept the parameters.

1. ArrayItem with `Id`/`Name` properties.

   ```
   public class ArrayItem
   {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Change action

   ```
       public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(IFormFile file, List<ArrayItem> myArray)
   {
       return Ok();
   }
   ```

**Update**

You need to remove `arrayKey: '[]'`, try code below:

```
app.service('crudService', function ($http, Upload) {

var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:50829';

this.uploadFile = function (file, array) {

    return Upload.upload({
        url: baseUrl + "/api/books/file/upload",
        //arrayKey: '[]',
        data: { file: file, array: array },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function (res) {

        return res;
    }, function (err) {

        throw err;
    });
}; 
});
```

Comment: I have tried updating as above but it does not work, still null. Is there something at the angularjs fileupload that needs to be updated?

Comment: @user1563677 Share us the screen shot of the request from web browser network tab. Is there any reproduceable project?

Comment: Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/dXMjNCs I can create a jsfiddle but how would I show/create my c# api code there?

Comment: @user1563677 What do you mean by **updated my api as: List<string> myArray**? You need to change `List<string> myArray` to `List<ArrayItem> myArray`.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo from my side..I have already updated as you have told to use ArrayItem but it does not work. Still is null

Comment: @kaka1234 It's strange that your request is `myArray[][Name]`, my test is `myArray[0][Name]`. Is there any reproduceable project?

Comment: No I dont have any. By reproducible project means uploading a full sample vs project somewhere?

Comment: @user1563677 Yeah, it seems to be related with your front end, you could try use the demo code in a new angular project and share us the demo project if this issue could be reproduceable.

Comment: @TaoZhou see my updated post for the sample project.

Comment: I have created sample project to show my issue:

https://github.com/kj1981/angularjsfileupload

Comment: @TaoZhou did you get a chance to review the project I shared?